# Updating partitioned table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm still a bit new to BigQuery. According to the [documentation deletes/updates on partitioned tables are now in beta](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language). However I have no clue, and did not find really information, on the syntax for that (I tried simply using a wildcard, which does not work, and don't really have an idea what to try else).

The use case is exported Google Analytics data, which is stored in tables partitioned by date; I want to nix out UserIds and other personally identifiable data.

Updating seems pretty straightforward:

```
UPDATE `123456789.ga_sessions_20180718`
SET userId = "1234abc"
WHERE userId = "2345bcd"
```

(although it takes an inane amount of time - can I speed this up ?), it's just that I have partitions for the last 13 months, so I need a way to apply this to all partitions at once.

Comment: Please define insane amount of time. I've seen 1-3 minutes for TB size tables.

Comment: @Pentium10, eight minutes with 10 GB of data processed (times 450 for all tables). Never mind, I clearly have wrong ideas about how BigQuery works and need to read up before I ask more embarrassing questions :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [partitioned table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) is a *single* table, not a collection of tables that happen to have a similar naming convention. In order to update multiple tables, as with the Google Analytics tables, you need to run an update statement for every table. To speed up the process, you could run multiple statements at once as long as you don't exceed [the limit of 50 concurrent queries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#query_jobs).

Comment: Yes, seems I misunderstood how this works. In querying I can access multiple tables via a where clause specifying a table_suffix (which in retrospect should have clued me in that these are not partitions) - is there no way to use a similar construct for updates ?

Comment: There is not. The wildcard is like doing a UNION ALL over multiple tables, and you can't run an update over a union of tables either.